# Нужно записать в третий файл текст из первого, заменив общее со вторым файлом

Tags: python

есть два файла: файл1.txt:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

файл2.txt:

```
2 4 6
```

нужно создать файл3.txt, который перепишет все с файл1.txt, но изменит цифры, которые есть в файл2.txt. Hу, например, должно выйти - файл3.txt:

```
1 (2) 3 (4) 5 (6)
```

Код примерно такой, но здесь в переменную `text` записывается лишь последняя замена.

```
f_1_read = open('file_1.txt')
f_1 = f_1_read.read()

f_2_read = open('file_2.txt')
f_2 = f_2_read.read().split()

f_1_read.close()
f_2_read.close()

f = open('file_3.html', 'a')
f.write('<html>\n<p>')
for i in f_2:
        text = f_1.replace(i, '<i>' + i + '</i>')
f.write(text)
f.write('</p>\n</html>')
f.close()
```

Comment: Товарищи закрыватели. Очень даже годный вопрос, почему нельзя ответить?

Comment: А почему третий файл HTML? Вроде же в первоначальном условии этого не было.

Comment: Общей задачи это не меняет. Вообще, изначально нужно создать html, что будет отображать все символи первого файла обычным текстом, а те, что есть и во втором - курсивом. Просто чтобы не объяснять вот так, я упростил задачу хотя бы, чтобы меньше было символов и был понятней алгоритм

Answer (score 1):

Немного измените цикл:

```
for i in f_2:
    text = f_1.replace(i, '<i>' + i + '</i>')
    f.write(text)
    f.write('</p>\n</html>')
f.close()
```

Т.е. записывайте в самом цикле

Или измените код:

```
f_1_read = open('file_1.txt')
f_1 = [i for i in f_1_read.read().split()]

f_2_read = open('file_2.txt')
f_resalt = ''.join(['({0}) '.format(i) if i in f_1 else (i + ' ') for i in f_2_read.read().split()]

f_1_read.close()
f_2_read.close()

f = open('file_3.txt', 'a')
f.write(f_result + '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: как я понимаю, здесь не выполняется `else (i + ' ')` так как получается `(2) (4) (6)` но почему, не знаю

Comment: Возможно нужно поменять файлы местами, из большего проверять меньший

Comment: точняк! спасибо, наконец-то

Comment: for i in f_2:
        text = f_1.replace(i, '<i>' + i + '</i>')
        f.write(text)
        f.write('</p>\n</html>')
    f.close()    а этот вариант не подходит из-за того, что каждая итерация меняет лишь одну цифру, а пишет весь файл (1 <i>2</i> 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 <i>4</i> 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 <i>6</i>)

Comment: Смотрите, Вы можете присвоить содержимое файла таким образом `a, b = f_1_read.read().split(), f_2_read.read().split()
    if len(a) > len(b): a, b = b, a     else: pass`

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял то:

```
def read_file(filename):
    #считать все числа из файла
    l = []
    for line in open(filename):
        l.extend(line.split())
    return l

def sort(value):
    if '(' in value:
        value = value.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
    return int(value)

l1 = read_file(FILENAME_1)
l2 = list(map(lambda s: '({s})'.format(s=s), read_file(FILENAME_2)))
l_done = list(l1) + list(l2)
l_done.sort(key=sort)

with open(FILENAME_3) as f:
    f.write(' '.join(l_done))
```

Comment: `FILENAME_3:`   12(2)34(4)56(6)      если есть (2) (4) (6), то 2 4 6 не нужно

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

def file_nums(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        yield from f.read().split()

files = '1.txt', '2.txt'
with open('3.txt', 'w') as f:  # Counter({'6': 2, '2': 2, '4': 2, '5': 1, '1': 1, '3': 1})
    f.write(str(Counter(chain(*map(file_nums, files)))))
```

Comment: Вашего ответа я вообще не понял. Или же вы поняли суть вопроса

Comment: Это более общий вариант ответа на ваш вопрос. В файл3 пишутся цифры из файл1 и файл2, а так же сколько раз они встречаются в файлах

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('1.txt', 'r') as f1:
    f1_data = f1.read().split()

with open('2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    f2_data = f2.read().split()

with open('3.html', 'w+') as f3:
    f3.write("""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>{0:s}</p>
    </body>
</html>
""".format(' '.join([('<i>{0:s}</i>'.format(char) if char in f2_data else char) for char in f1_data])))
```